# How i can grant access to a directory of a PaaS (Symfony CLoud)?

Tags: php, docker, symfony, cloud

I m using the Symfony Cloud to deploy my website, but the access to a directory is denied. 
**It's working fine on local !!**

[image]

I tried to connect from ssh with

```
symfony env:ssh
```

But i didn't suceed to **chmod** because I don't have admin rights to use **su**

[image]
[image]

I also think is about a configuration on a symfony cloud files , but I found nothing about it.

**How can I grant access to a directory on Symfony Cloud?**

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your directories are all set to read-only by default on symfony cloud. This is the reason why it's working on local, not in production.

Look at your `symfony.cloud.yaml` file, there is already a line which set the `var` directory as writable. You could reproduce this line for your `images/products` directory

```yaml
mounts:
    "/var": {source: local, source_path: var}
    "/public/images/products": {source: local, source_path: products}
```

You can find more documentation about configuration [on this chapter](https://symfony.com/doc/master/cloud/config.html#mounts)

Comment: Waw thanks Alexandre, it work fine now . there is a link on symfony that explain this? Again, thank you

Comment: You're welcome! I edited my answer to give you link on symfony cloud that explains it.